# Implement an view controller container without using build-in containers?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I'm new to *iOS* programming, so I want to dive in the View Controller Container concept.
I'm learning by *"monkey see monkey do"* :D and I wanted to make a Slide-Out navigation (like Facebook/Gmail/Path) nothing original.

I've found different implementations, but this [one](https://github.com/beat843796/CHSlideController) , made by [Clemens Hammerl](https://github.com/beat843796), seemed to be very simple so I started messing around with it to see whats is going on. He uses a UINavigationViewController and a UITableViewController as the ViewController's for his container (CHSlideController).

From what I've read so far, this 2 ViewController's are Containers themselves, and felt a little strange about this, so I wanted to send normal ViewController's to my Container but I cannot see the views of those ViewControllers.

The thing that I what to ask you about is, **how to implement an view controller container without using other build-in containers like UINavigationViewController / <strike>UITableViewController</strike> / UITabViewController / ...?**

Do I need to overwrite some methods or fallow some protocol?

Thanks.

I'm only interested from iOS SDK 5.0+.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, i don't get the purpose of this question but anyway! :-)

If it's just for learning purpose as you mentionend, then check out [this](http://www.hollance.com/2011/11/mhtabbarcontroller-a-custom-tab-bar-for-ios-5-using-the-new-container-apis/) rather simple example for view controller containment under iOS5+.

If you want to know why view controller containment was a PITA prior to to iOS5, check out [this](http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.co.at/2011/08/writing-high-quality-view-controller.html) excelent article.

As a side note, UITableViewController is not a view controller container!
UITabBarController, UINavigationController or UISplitViewController for example are containers!